# How do I use CROSS APPLY in this situation?

Tags: t-sql

I have an inline TVF that accept a primary key of a table and computes a value out of the row with that primary key (actually a table with that value as part of the select, but whatever).

Now I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT something
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY thefunction(table1primarykey) func
     ON func.computedvalue = func.computedvalue(table2primarykey)
```

Problem is I did not use table2 yet, and could not do it, because the only way table1 and table2 are joined is via the same function return value.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: So table1 and table2 should be joined via the computedvalue column returned from thefunction??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    CROSS APPLY thefunction(table1primarykey)
) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    CROSS APPLY thefunction(table2primarykey)
) AS t2 ON t1.computedvalue = t2.computedvalue
```

Comment: I found the solution myself I just did:

    SELECT *
    FROM function...
    CROSS APPLY function...
    JOIN table1 ON ...
    JOIN table2 ON ...

Due to what additional values my function returns, this should work :) thanks anyway :)